# convert txt to csv using shell script (blank included)

Tags: string, shell, csv, parsing

how to convert .txt to .csv using shell script ??
Input

```
A B 10 C d e f g
H I 88 J k l m n
O P 3  Q r s t u
```

Expected Output - After  4 blank, don't change to ','

```
A,B,10,C,d e f g
H,I,88,J,k l m n
O,P,3,Q,r s t u
```

I was trying but can't handle "d e f g"

```
$ cat input.txt | tr -s '[:blank:]' ',' > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed -s 's/\s\{1,\}/,/g'  input.txt > output.txt`

The output for your input is

```
A,B,10,C,d,e,f,g
H,I,88,J,k,l,m,n
0,P,3,Q,r,s,t,u
```

Explanation:

`sed -s 's/<searchText>/<replacetext>/<flags>'`

Search Text `\s\{1,\}`
`\s` matches any whitespace `\{1,\}` matches 1 or more consecutive characters.

Replace Text `,` - Replace with a comma

Flags `g` Replace all occurrences on a given line.

EDIT:

You only want to change the first 4 spaces into ',' then this sed

`sed -s 's/\(\S*\)\s*\(\S*\)\s*\(\S*\)\s*\(\S*\)\s*/\1,\2,\3,\4,/' input.txt > output.txt`

should work.

Explanation:

`\(\S*\)\s*` is repeated 4 times. It matches first `\S*` all non-whitespace characters and saves the value (because of the `\(` and `\)` surrounding the field. The `\s*` then matches all whitespace characters. 4 times for the 4 sets.

The replace is now `\1,\2,\3,\4,`. It means take the first saved value `\1` add a comma ',' then take the second saved value `\2` and so on.

The output you get for this is:

```
A,B,10,C,d e f g
H,I,88,J,k l m n
0,P,3,Q,r s t u
```

You should be easily able to modify the number of spaces you replace by following the pattern.

Comment: plz check my expected result again .. I don't want change blank to ',' after 4 blank ..

Comment: Is there anything determining the which blank you want to stop at or is always the fourth one? Also are there always the same number of blanks?

Comment: change four spaces to comma from the front of each line. Thank u for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you are attempting with `expr substr` in POSIX shell. Basically, just `read` and split each line into the first `10` chars and remaining chars and call `sed` on the first 10, e.g.

```
while read -r line; do 
    first=$(expr substr "$line" 1 10)
    second=$(expr substr "$line" 11 20)
    printf "%s%s\n" "$(echo "$first" | sed 's/[ ][ ]*/,/g')" "$second"
done < file
```

Simply paste it into your console to test, e.g.

```
$ while read -r line; do
>     first=$(expr substr "$line" 1 10)
>     second=$(expr substr "$line" 11 20)
>     printf "%s%s\n" "$(echo "$first" | sed 's/[ ][ ]*/,/g')" "$second"
> done < file
A,B,10,C,d e f g
H,I,88,J,k l m n
O,P,3,Q,r s t u
```

Let me know if that works for you.

For advanced shells that allow redirection from subshells (e.g. bash), you can use `paste` and `cut` along with `sed`, e.g.

```
$ paste -d ' ' <(cut -c -10 file | sed 's/[ ][ ]*/,/g') <(cut -c 12- file)
A,B,10,C,d e f g
H,I,88,J,k l m n
O,P,3,Q,r s t u
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use `awk` command:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++)printf "%s%s",$i,i<5?",":" ";print $NF}' input > output

$ cat output
A,B,10,C,d e f g
H,I,88,J,k l m n
O,P,3,Q,r s t u
```

Brief explanation,

- `for (i=1;i<NF;i++)`: parse each field separated by space in each record
- `printf "%s%s",$i,i<5?",":" "`: print `:` if `i<5`, otherwise print `" "`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='10 2 2 2' 'gsub(" +",",",$1)' file
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `paste`, `cut`, `tr` & `bash` method:

   ```
   paste -d ' ' <(cut -d ' ' -f 1-5 file | tr ' ' ,) <(cut -d ' ' -f 6- file)
   ```

   Or, with *GNU* `cut`, there's no need for `tr`:

   ```
   paste -d ' ' <(cut -d ' ' --output-delimiter , -f 1-5 file ) \
                <(cut -d ' ' -f 6- file)
   ```
2. Shell script method:

   ```
   while IFS=" " read a b c d e ; do echo "$a,$b,$c,$d,$e" ; done < file
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the fun:

This converts the first five groups of one or more spaces on the line to commas:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=4;i++){sub(/ +/,",")}}1'
```

Or if bytes must be saved, you can have the same effect a little less clearly:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i++<=4;sub(/ +/,","))}1'
```

You could also use `sed`. If your `printf` (or your shell is bash, with its built-in printf), you can rely on the fact that `printf` will repeat a single format when fed multiple data operands.

```
sed -n -E -e "$(printf 's/(([^ ]+) +)/\\2,/%d;' {4..1})p"
```

This uses `-E` to denote an ERE instead of sed's default BRE. Salt to taste.

And of course, I'll add another bash-only option. This relies on an array.

```
while read -a arr; do printf "%s," "${arr[@]:0:4}"; echo "${arr[@]:4}"; done
```

All these solutions can be used on a pipe. The awk and sed solutions can be pointed directly at a file, and the while loop can of course take input redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk we can get the required o/p:

```
awk -F " " '{ print $1","$2","$3","$4,$(NF-2)," ",$(NF-1)," ",$(NF) }' shell.txt > output.txt
```